# Branched website - All .SLN files opening the same branch - VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, branching-and-merging

I recently added branching to a website solution (webforms) in Visual Studio 2012. I now have a main branch and 2 dev branches.

The problem is that the when I open the solution file, it always opens the DEV1 branch.  I go to Source Control Explorer, drill down to the DEV2 branch and double click the .sln file and assume I'm opening the DEV2 branch.  But when I check changes in, they always list the checked in files as located in: `$/MyDev/MyApp-DEV1/MyWebSite`.  The same thing happens if I do anything in the main branch.

How do I get the .sln file in the DEV2 branch to actually open the DEV2 solution instead of DEV1?

Comment: Did you create the branch by using the TFS branch command in the UI or command prompt?

Comment: Do your solution files have absolute or relative paths to the projects?

Comment: I used the UI to create the branches.  I'm not sure about your second question.  Each branch is mapped to its own absolute local path, e.g. `C:\Users\...\Projects\MyApp-DEV1`.  And the Source location is relative, e.g. `$/MyDev/MyApp-DEV1`.  But that's probably not what you're asking.  I'm not sure how to see how the actual solution is mapped.

Comment: If you open the problem SLN file with a text editor, does it have relative paths ("../folder/project.proj") or abolute ("c:\folder\project.proj")?

Comment: Hmm, they're relative, but the .sln files are identical, all pointing to `"..\MyApp-DEV1\MyWebSite\"`  I tried just editing the file in notepad, but I'm getting errors opening the one I edited to point to DEV2.

Comment: I closed (and saved) the solution & reopened it and didn't get errors opening it the 2nd time.  But it looks like VS _corrected_ the error by changing the .sln file back to pointing at DEV1. :(

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to StingyJack, I think I got this cleared up.

From his suggestion I looked at the .sln files in a text editor and saw that they were identical (all 3 pointed at the DEV1 branch).  I changed the paths in the DEV2 .sln file, and at first it didn't work, but it turned out the local path was messed up.  I removed the local mapping for the DEV2 branch, remapped it, and ran a get all.

After doing this, I can finally use my different branches as they are supposed to be used!